# How to set LaunchScreen image width constraint to superview in xamarin iOS project storyboard file?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, splash-screen

I am implementing a splash screen for my app. I just came to know about storyboard constraints to support multiple devices. Basically, I feel it very difficult to understand it as a beginner in this, also I see there is no apt documentation in xamarin also. **I want to know the steps to set an imageview width to its super view (View controller)**.

I see what I should do from here, [Visual studio Xamarin iOS launchscreen storyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209563/visual-studio-xamarin-ios-launchscreen-storyboard-layout). But, how do I add those constraints, totally no idea..?! Particularly imageview width and height to superview, trailing and leading

Now, I can only know how to set the constraints in designer by dragging, I'v only learnt to center the image to super view in X and Y (Horizontally and vertically). **There is no button to add constraints. How to add leading and trailing constraints? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for Windows**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working.

Step 1: Open storyboard file with lowest screen resolution device set (iPhone 4s) and drag & drop an imageview to fill the view controller.

Step 2: Set the uiimageview source from resources/image assets.

Step 3: Click on the image -> Properties Tab -> Layouts section. You will see like this

[image]

Step 4 : Properties -> Layout -> Under **View** group, there is title called **Arrange**, there is a **autosizing box** and **example box.**

Step 5 : You should click all the I-bars and lines in the center **to make it red** like below to fill the width (you can see that reflecting in the example box as you click)

[image]

Now, **SAVE** and then switch to other devices, you should have that UIImageview filling the device's height and width.

This will be very useful for important UI auto designs like splash screen.

Comment: The autosizing box is not appearing for me when I select the UIImage element, it only shows the fill Parent and Position buttons. I know I have seen it there before with other images...

Comment: I am having the same issue, there is not Autosizing box. @hvaughan3 were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @Reza No I never did figure this one out.

Comment: @hvaughan3 took me awhile, but I figured it out https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/180158/how-to-set-an-imageview-to-center-in-ios-launchstoryboard